# Is it possible to precompile xib/storyboard files?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xib

We have a large monolithic app: 700 ObjC files, 300 Swift files and up to 100 xib and storyboard files.

We are looking for any techniques that would help us to optimize the app build time.

One idea is to precompile some of the stable xibs/storyboards so that we don't compile them every time we build the app. Is there a technique to do this?

P.S. I know that xib are compiled only the first time, however like it is with iOS frameworks which are precompiled binaries, the question is how to do the same for xib/storyboard files.

Comment: I dont think there is any precompile technique for XIB/Storyboard. Even PCH is available in obj-c for file but not in swift. Your app is very huge so it takes time to build.